# SQL string or binary data would be truncated , column name

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

We have simply UI application for which we use a SQL Server database. The issue is when user giving data more than the column length and hence gets an error:

> String or binary data would be truncated

Is it possible to find the column causing this issue at runtime? Our application is designed in such a way that, UI label and column name is in sync. So if we are available to find column name at run time, then we can let user to correct it then and there.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: That is one of longest running and irritating issues in sql server. The engine does not tell you which column is at fault even though it obviously knows. You should fix your application to not allow more characters than the columns allow. Yes it is irritating but for more than a decade (or probably close to two now), this has been an issue that many people wish they would fix.

Comment: No. Go vote. https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32908417-binary-or-string-data-would-be-truncated-error In the meantime, write your application so that the field length can't exceed the column length.

Comment: ...you won't have a column to track down if your application already limits the strings to the same length the database does. Did you look at [the 600+ other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%22string%20or%20binary%20data%20would%20be%20truncated%22&mixed=0) that already address this error message?

Comment: If this is a mvc app, then just add a `[StringLength]` attribute on your property so that you get client and server side validation.

Answer (score -1):

The error message is pretty clear: the data you are trying to fit in such a field is too big for the field itself. Check your insert statement.

Then look at the column definition: you have a defined length of (say) 10 or 50 characters but the data you are trying to insert is longer than that.
Either increase the size of the column, or reduce the size of the data you are sending.

i hope its may be helps you..